# Graph of the Region of Integration

Tags: integration

I am trying to draw the region of integration in this case using the fact that square root of $y$ is equal to the parabola $x^2$, however I am still not able to plot a graph of this region. 
Mainly I am stuck at the idea of square root of $y$ can you please explain what’s the difference and how should I proceed in order to solve this problem?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region is bounded on the left by the parabola $y=x^2,$ on the right by the line $x=2,$ below by the the line $y=0,$ and above by the the line $y=1.$  You say you are stuck at the idea of $\sqrt{y}.$  Why is that?  We are told that $y>0,$ so $\sqrt{y}<x$ is equivalent to $y < x^2.$